# scipy.optimize.minimize changes the shape of x0 (initial guess) during minimisation

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy-optimize-minimize

**Background (potentially irrelevant):** I am using random features for a sparse kernel approximation which is then used in a vanilla Bayesian linear regression setting. To optimise the two hyper-parameters [gamma, var_y] I am using the reparameterisation trick and minimising the variational upper bound `-E[log(p(y|f(x)))] + KL(q(w)||p(w))`.

**Issue:** During the optimisation procedure, the x0 parameter (initial guess) changes shape from [gamma, var_y] to [[gamma, var_y]] causing the minimization procedure to fail. This is because when x0 is unpacked there is only one value rather than two. Strangely, this does not occur every time minimize is called.

Manually reshaping x0 when it changes shape causes an error within the minimize function and is also side stepping the problem.

**Code:**

```
def kl_divergence(mu, cov):
    n = mu.shape[0]
    kl = 0.5 * (-np.log(np.linalg.det(cov)) - n + np.trace(cov) + np.dot(mu.T,mu))
    return kl

def upper_bound(self, x0):

    print('x0: ', x0)       

    ############################
    # Unpack error occurs here #
    ############################
    gamma, var_y = np.exp(x0)

    X = np.array([-4,-2,-1.5,0.3,1,2,3.5,4.5]).reshape(-1,1)
    Y = np.array([-0.35,0.5,1.5,1.9,0.2,-2.2,-1.5,-1]).reshape(-1,1)

    # Returns the MAP weights (mu), covariance matrix (S) and design matrix (phi)
    mu, S, phi = bayes_regressor(X, Y, gamma, var_y)

    # KL divergence between posterior and prior on the weights
    kl = kl_divergence(mu, S)

    # Gaussian log likelihood
    N = X.shape[0]
    log_p = -(N/2)*np.log(2*np.pi*var_y) - ((0.5/var_y)*(Y - phi.dot(mu))**2).mean()

    # Variational upper bound
    ub = -log_p + kl

    return ub
```

Run the minimization:

```
x0 = [0, 0]

result = scipy.optimize.minimize(upper_bound, x0)
```

Printing x0 on each iteration reveals the following:

```
x0:  [0. 0.]
x0:  [1.49011612e-08 0.00000000e+00] 
x0:  [0.00000000e+00 1.49011612e-08]
...
...
x0:  [-0.03153053 -5.35141768]
x0:  [-0.03153053 -5.35141769]
x0:  [[-0.03153053 -5.35141769]]
```

Where the last line exhibits the shape change. The following error is thrown from `np.exp(x0)`:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

**Update:** Convergence plot showing objective function evaluations for 4 minimisation runs (all failed with same issue). Hyperparameter plot showing how the hyperparam values vary during minimisation.

[objective function evaluations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nof38.png)

[hyperparameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8y7Rm.png)

Comment: How is convergence determined here? How does it break out of it?

Comment: I've been using scipy's default minimize tolerance. It solves consistently at tol=1e-3 but fails at tol=1e-4. I would have thought higher tolerances would be achievable.

Comment: You may want to plot the objective to see if the solution oscillates on tighter constraints. Not sure I would trust 1e-3

Comment: I've plotted both the objective and the hyperparam values (see update in main text) and while there is some oscillation it occurs early in the minimisation process. Values then settle before the same issue occurs and minimisation fails.

Comment: Changed to Nelder-Mead which seems to have solved the issue. Although still not sure why other methods seem to cause an issue.

Comment: Cool. Yeah some of the methods are more numerically stable than others in the world of limited precision :)